# Navigation from Shell page to tabbed page cause issue in ios. -Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app I am using shell component.I have a tabbed page named  **TimeSheetsTab**. When I navigate from Shell tabbed page to the TimeSheetsTab, in ios it only shows a black page. In android it works fine. Please refer the screenshots.

[image: ios]
[image: android]

**My Appshell page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"             
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample.Views"
             x:Class="Sample.AppShell">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Dashboard" Icon="icon_dashboard.png" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Dashboard}" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Notifications" Icon="icon_notifications.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Notifications}" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Account" Icon="icon_user.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Account}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>


</Shell>
```

**My Dashboard which is the first tab page of shell**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"   
             mc:Ignorable="d"                   
             Title="Dashboard"            
             x:Class="Sample.Views.Dashboard">
    <ContentPage.Content>
         <Button BackgroundColor="Black"   Clicked="Button_Clicked"   Text="Click to tabpapge"  >                    
         </Button>              
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Button Click for navigating to tabbed page**

```
   private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabPage(), true);           
        }
```

**My tabbed page**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Sample.Views"
             BarBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource NavigationBarColor}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"      
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             Shell.BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource NavigationBarColor}"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
             x:Class="Sample.Views.TimeSheetsTab">
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Timesheets" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"></Label>
            <Image Source="search.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="25" Margin="0,2,10,2"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>


    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <Views:PendingTimesheets Title="Pending" IconImageSource="icon_pending.png"/>
        <Views:ApprovedTimesheets Title="Approved" IconImageSource="icon_approved.png"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

I didnt added the code of TimesheetTab's child pages, because it shows properly when navigate directly to it. What will be the cause of issue in ios? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you use a ContentPage for "PendingTimesheets" and "ApprovedTimesheets"? Does it work if you try it without Children (to check where the problem is)

Comment: @D.Nehl Yes I am using content page for PendingTimesheets and ApprovedTimesheets

Comment: @D.Nehl If I navigate to PendingTimesheets  directly, It will work

Comment: Why are you using TabbedPages if you have a Shell navigation setup why not just use shell? May be check this out for more information https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-bottom-tabbed-page-using-shell/

Comment: @FreakyAli  so should I use another shell for my inner tab instead of TabbedPages ?

Comment: Can't the shell tabs appear there? why do you need the second shell?

Comment: @FreakyAli Bro please look at my android screenshot.. I need a seperate tab there.The screenshot is the second page

Comment: @FreakyAli Iam talking about the "Pending " and "approved " tabs

Comment: Are those two different pages or just the Data differs? If its only the data the differs why not just use two buttons and do it in a single contentpage!!!

Comment: @FreakyAli They are different pages with different data.

Comment: Then use a segmented control do not use tabbed page here

Comment: @FreakyAli can you explain?

Comment: what's your Xamarin.Forms version ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT xamarin.forms version : 4.3.0.947036